# Symfony2 UnitTests fail at first run, succeeds on all subsequent runs

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

When I run phpunit on my Symfony2 project, the tests always fail at first run:

```
$ phpunit -c app src/Project/MyBundle/Tests/Controller/SomeTest.php 
PHPUnit 3.7.19 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from src/main/app/phpunit.xml

E

Time: 1 second, Memory: 24.25Mb

There was 1 error:

1) Project\MyBundle\Tests\Controller\RegistrationTest::testStdRegistration
PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Swift_Events_SendListener' not found in src/main/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Plugins/MessageLogger.php on line 19
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() -:0
PHP   2. require_once() -:542


FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

If I then restart the tests, everything passes well. No errors. I figured that it all boils down to the existence of the file cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php
This file does not exist before the tests run the first time. After this run, it is created and used in the following tests. I was always under the impressions that Symfony2 makes sure, all relevant files are created BEFORE the first test runs, but this seems not to be the case. 
So how can I solve this issue? Should I try to warm up the cache manually before the tests start or do I have to modify my tests in order to wait for the cache files to be created?

Answer (score 2):

Warm up your test environment **cache** prior to executing the tests in order to avoid this error.

```
app/console cache:warmup --env=test
```

Comment: Thank you for this! It solves the problem. Nevertheless I am curious why Symfony does not create the required file when bootstrapping the tests.